# Description of summary report data: condensed, summarized, something else?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm writing a technical description about the usage of personal detail data in a system. Some reports are generated from that data, but those reports do not have anyone's personal details in them.

For example, you could have a webshop with orders, where for each order one would store the customer's name, product code, and date of order. A report could be a monthly summary of what products were ordered and how many of each were ordered.

So I'm trying to say something like "**These reports do not handle the personal data in any way as they only consist of _____ data**". (Feel free to rewrite the entire sentence if that helps.)

It's certainly not *anonymized* nor *pseudonymized*, as there would be no place for any kind of user name in that report. Words I'm thinking of would be "*summarized*" or "*condensed*". Would those work, or would there be some even more appropriate word?

Comment: I'd just say "non-personal data", eg "These reports do not contain any personal data about the users."

Comment: in this particular case, I would say 'stock level data'

Comment: Stopping the sentence at "... *in any way*" would achieve your purpose.

Comment: *A report could be a monthly summary...* - that sounds like the answer to your question. The data is summarized by month.

Comment: As Davo suggested, *summaries* as for instance: *These reports consist of summaries only, with no personal data/details/information.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Aggregate" was the word I was looking for.